# Kafka-Producers Too many open files

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Getting this error with Kafka Producer

> Too many open files

We are caching the producer by tenant id, using the same producer to send the message.
Not closing the connection..

```
[root@talent_dev bin]# ls -l /proc/26262/fd | wc -l 4500
```

Comment: How many tenant id's are there?

Comment: testing with one tenant

Comment: what do you mean that you are caching the producer by tenant id?

Comment: 1. Creating KafkaProducer for each tenant and putting into ConcurrentHashMap. 2. Check if KafkaProducer is available for that Tenant we don't create a new producer, use the same producer to send message